# search keyword in table list

Tags: php, laravel

I want to search keyword base on the word on table but when I search there is no output and no error display but the url display the keyword for example http://127.0.0.1:8000/users?keyword=sulaimani

Index.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('users.search') }}" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="keyword" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
             <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search
          </button>
</form>
```

UserController.php

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $keyword = $request->get('keyword');
    $users = User::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')->orwhere('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')->paginate(4); 
    return view('users.index')->with(compact('users'));
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('user/search', 'UserController@search')->name('users.search');
```

Answer (score 1):

First try to find out the name or email like "sulaimani" in your users table. If they are returning what you need then come to the code.
Just dump and die the variable $keyword and see what your are getting (dd($keyword))

Or you can just change the same like:

```
$keyword = $request->keyword;
```

Now in dump and die (dd($keyword)) if you are getting your input then just remove dd and hit the following query using eloquent,

```
$users = User::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")->OrWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")->paginate(4);
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: In my situation  User::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%") was not working , when I changed that to User::where('name', 'like', "%{$keyword}%") it worked. I don't know why , but this may help someone

Comment: Try after clearing your views and route etc by firing the following command

```php artisan optimize```